# Matlab: How to implement expectation of product of hermitian matrix

Tags: matlab, signal-analysis, matrix

I want to implement the following equation in Matlab:

$\mathbf {R}_\mathbf {z}^a(\tilde{f}) = \mathbb {E} \left[\mathbf {z}(\tilde{f}) \mathbf {z}^H(\tilde{f}+a) \right]$, $ \tilde{f} \in \left[0, f_s-a \right] $

where $ \mathbf {z}(\tilde{f}) $ is a matrix, and $ a $ takes values in the interval $ \left[0, f_s-a \right] $. 
I am not sure how to implement the expectation operation, Is there some equivalent implementation in the time domain?

Comment: I suppose the expectation is calculated over the distribution of random matrix $\mathbf{z}$? Because "the expected value of a random variable, intuitively, is the long-run average value of repetitions of the same experiment it represents", how about just generating, say $10^6$, realizations of $\mathbf{z}$ then averaging the corresponding $\mathbf{R}$?

Comment: @AlexTP, Pay attention that you are right under the assumption of Ergodicity of the random process.

Comment: @Royi totally argee ...